# Membership.GeneratePassword doesn't conform to numberOfNonAlphaNumericCharacters

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

I'm using Membership.GeneratePassword(10, 0).

i.e. Number of Non-AlphaNumeric characters should be zero, as per the MSDN defintion: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.generatepassword(VS.80).aspx

However, I noted that this didn't conform to what I expected. Is there a bug in the algorithm, or is it normal to see this? I still see a fair amount of punctuation characters in the password that is generated when I expect to see zero.

As a test, I threw a Grid on an ASP.NET page and wrote this to see what the output was:

```
public partial class Verification : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int max = 0; // change as required
        List<MemberPassword> list = new List<MemberPassword>();
        for (int i = 0; i <= 20; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j <= max; j++)
            {
                string display = String.Format("Membership.GeneratePassword(10, {0})", j);
                list.Add(new MemberPassword(i, j, Membership.GeneratePassword(10, j), display));
            }
        }

        this.GridView1.DataSource = list;
        this.GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}

public class MemberPassword
{
    public MemberPassword(int id, int numNonAlphaNum, string password, string display)
    {
        this.Id = id;
        this.NumNonAlphaNum = numNonAlphaNum;
        this.Password = password;
        this.Display = display;
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int NumNonAlphaNum { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string  Display { get; set; }
}
```

Although the results show a progression towards more and more punctuation, the actual requirement is not honoured.

Have I got the wrong end of the stick here or am I losing the plot? :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That documentation is out of date. Try this one:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.generatepassword.aspx

> The **minimum** number of punctuation characters in the generated password.

Comment: Nice spot. I guess I could target the 2.0 framework, or just write my own password generator. Thanks Mark.

Answer (score 0):

I am only using .NET 2.0 so I think this is a bug, or more likely a mis-print in their .NET 2.0 documentation seeing as in 3.0 and above they have the word **minimum**!